# Argument of type '"MY_EVENTS_LOAD"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>' in yeild takeLatest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

I have a error on typescript, I'm using Redux and Saga as middleware, these is the error:

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
>   error.
>       Argument of type '"MY_EVENTS_LOAD"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel'.

I want create a watcher, here:

```
export default function* watcher() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.MY_EVENTS_LOAD, getListEventsByUserSaga);
}
```

And in my saga file have the function

```
export function* getListEventsByUserSaga(OwnerId: string) {
  try {
    const events = yield getEventsByOwnerId(OwnerId);
    yield put(actions.fetchMyEventsListUserSuccess(events));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.fetchMyEventsListUserFailure(error.message));
  }
}
```

this happen when I do my action:

```
export const fetchMyEventsListUserLoad = (OwnerId: string) => {
  return {
    type: MY_EVENTS_LOAD,
    OwnerId,
  };
};
```

How can implement these of the correct way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you could do (what I did in my case, at least) was what was pointed out in [this](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1883#issuecomment-509493260) link. Currently, you seem only to output the `OwnerId` string to the generator and this shouldn't work like it is, as the generator there basically takes the arguments dispatched, an object with the type and the rest of the arguments sent to the dispatcher. The "correct" way to do would be to have a type definition that encompasses the type, with something like:

```js
type Params = { OwnerId: string, type: string }
export function* getListEventsByUserSaga({ OwnerId }: Params) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your getListEventsByUserSaga generator, you are declaring the action as `{OwnerId:string}` without a type. If you try to declare it with a type, this will get rid of the error. You can use [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet).

```
export function* getListEventsByUserSaga({OwnerId} : ReturnType<typeof fetchMyEventsListUserLoad>) {
  try {
    // code
  } catch (error) {
    // code
  }
}
```

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1883

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
export function* getListEventsByUserSaga(action: { payload: any; }) {
...
//logic
...
}
```

use this

```
export function* getListEventsByUserSaga(action: any) {
...
//logic
...
}
```

**it works for me**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this code by adding a payload to the object like this.

```
    export function* getListEventsByUserSaga({payload: OwnerId}: PayloadAction<string>) {
      try {
        const events = yield getEventsByOwnerId(OwnerId);
        yield put(actions.fetchMyEventsListUserSuccess(events));
      } catch (error) {
        yield put(actions.fetchMyEventsListUserFailure(error.message));
      }
    }
```